# array doesnt start at 0 after pushing but starts at 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been debugging for a while now but decided to ask some professionals on why after I push elements into the array it starts at 0. here's my code.

```
 var Collect = [{
 }];
```

Collect is initialized

So this is my function collecting elements from firebase.

```
function getDataFirebase(){
return new Promise (function(resolve,reject){
    refReview.on("value", function(snap){
    var data = snap.val();
                for(var key in data){              
                        Collect.push({
                        RevieweeName: data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
                        ReviewerName: data[key].reviewerID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].reviewerID.lastname),
                        rating:data[key].rating,
                        content: data[key].content
                        })
                        }//end of for loop

    }); //end of snap 
    resolve();
```

});
}

after collecting all the data from firebase I printed the Collect array in the console and it shows this, 
[image]

I wanted to start in 0 not 1.

Comment: you add a blank entry when you define the array initially

Comment: For what it's worth, the usual JavaScript convention is for most variable names to start with lower-case letters.

Comment: ill take note. thank youuuu

Answer (score 5):

You initialized the array with a single empty object:

```
var Collect = [{
 }];
```

If you want it to be really empty, don't put the empty object initializer in there:

```
var Collect = [];
```

Comment: what should i do? i cant initialized an element in the array first since the data are retrieved from firebase first.

Comment: @kenny I don't understand the question, but I extended the answer: just make it an empty array.